# Comparing and returning index in lodash

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

```
var x = [{a:1, b:4,c:5}, {a:1, b:2,c:7}];
var y = [{a:1, b:2,c:6}, {a:1, b:2,c:8}];
```

I want to compare based on first 2 key i.e a,b and get the index if it is unequal. In above example output should be fetched as 0 since b value is nt equal. How do we achieve in javascript or Lodash ? Thank you.

Comment: Can you share your first approach?

Comment: I am not getting any approach wanted to know if this is achieved through lodash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to compare two objects in an array by first two keys, here's a working example. Please, feel free to elaborate.

```
var x = [{a:1, b:4,c:5},{a:1, b:2,c:7}]; 
var y = [{a:1, b:2,c:6}, {a:1, b:2,c:8}];

function customizer(obj1, obj2) {
    const [a, b] = Object.keys(obj1).slice(0, 2);

  return obj1[a] === obj2[a] && obj1[b] === obj2[b];
}

xIsEqual = _.isEqualWith(x[0], x[1], customizer);
yIsEqual = _.isEqualWith(y[0], y[1], customizer);

console.log(xIsEqual); // false
console.log(yIsEqual); // true
```

Comment: Thanks Boris this is what i was looking for.I have 1 more query  for

Comment: Sweet! Could you please accept the answer and upvote it if it's not too much trouble?

Answer (score 3):

So you want a compare function which will compare an array of object in which you want index of an object whose two properties `a` and `b` are not equal.

Below implementation return such index(0-base) if exit else return `-1`.

```
function compare(x,y){
   for(let i=0;i<x.length && i<y.length;i++){
   if(x[i].a!=y[i].a || x[i].b!=y[i].b)
        return i;
   }
   return -1;
}
var x = [{a:1, b:4,c:5}, {a:1, b:2,c:7}];
var y = [{a:1, b:2,c:6}, {a:1, b:2,c:8}];
console.log(compare(x,y)); //0
y = [{a:1, b:4,c:6}, {a:1, b:2,c:8}];
console.log(compare(x,y));//-1
y = [{a:1, b:4,c:6}, {a:1, b:3,c:8}];
console.log(compare(x,y));//1
```

Hope this you want.

Comment: var x = [{a:1, b:4,c:5},{a:1, b:2,c:7},{a:1, b:3,c:8}]; 
var y = [{a:1, b:2,c:6}, {a:1, b:2,c:8},{a:1, b:2,c:8}];
var xrr=[];
function customizer(obj1, obj2) {
    const [a, b] = Object.keys(obj1).slice(0, 2);

  return obj1[a] === obj2[a] && obj1[b] === obj2[b];
}

for(i=0;i<x.length;i++){
var xIsEqual = _.isEqualWith(x[i], y[i], customizer);
if(xIsEqual ===false){
xrr.push(i);
}
}
console.log(xrr);

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter an array on a specific condition, you can use `filter()` :

```
y.filter(d => d.a !== d.b);
```

With Lodash:

```
_.filter(y, d => d.a !== d.b);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't rely on an order of object keys, 'cause iteration over object keys is implementation-dependent. It could differ from browser to browser.

Read this [note](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Cross-browser_notes).

For example, run the following code:

```js
const obj1 = { a: 'a', 100: 'b', 2: 'c' };
console.log('object literal', Object.keys(obj1));
// at least in chrome it would be ["2", "100", "a"]
const obj2 = {};
obj2['a'] = 'a'; 
obj2['100'] = 'b';
obj2['2'] = 'b';
console.log('object with keys added in a specific order', Object.keys(obj2));
// same ["2", "100", "a"]
```